# Realloc - incompatible types when assigning

Tags: c

Is it possible to realloc variable defined like this: `char string[128]` ?
I have a piece of code like this:

```
...
count = strlen(string);
if ((string = realloc(string, (count + 2) * sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
    ...
}
...
```

and compilers says: "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[128]’ from type ‘void *’". Similar operation works for definition `char *string`.

Comment: it's undefined behavior. you should expect anything to happen as consequence.

Answer (score 3):

`char string[128];` defines a statically sized array of `char`s. There is no need to allocate memory for it, but, on the other hand, there is no way to resize the memory portion.

To use a dynamically sized array use `char *string;` with `string = malloc(128)`, `string = realloc(string, newsize)` and `free(string)` when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

`char string[128];` allocates space, so string is not a true pointer.

If you had string defined as follows it will work:  `char *string;`